# Vagrant: How can I run the provision script in my Vagrantfile from the private repository?

Tags: bash, shell, github, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have a private repository on Github, it contains a script that I would like to use for Vagrant provision. Since my repository is private, I need to give access to my script. Tell me how to do this, please.

I tried to give access using the token in the link, but this causes this error:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tempfile.rb:133:in `initialize': Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/Stas/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20181004-3104-19o2zkk.sh?token=blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah (Errno::EINVAL)
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tempfile.rb:133:in `open'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tempfile.rb:133:in `block in initialize'
    ...
```

Obviously, the Vagrant is not able to trim GET parameters and filename.

My system: Windows.
I know about [this way](https://stefanscherer.github.io/access-private-github-repos-in-vagrant-up/), but I need another solution.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred solution is the one you link to, using SSH agent forwarding. We use that with Vagrant here, and it works very nicely.

As an alternative, you could use [a GitHub deploy key](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/) to give Vagrant read-only access to your private repository. You can put the unencrypted private key in the Vagrant directory, so it appears in `/vagrant`. Then, in the provision script, install it as `/root/.ssh/id_rsa`. Remember to set the permissions of `/root/.ssh` and `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` so group and other can't access them. After that, `git clone` should work.

I'd note that using unencrypted private keys is bad practice, though sometimes unavoidable with deploy keys. Take special care to ensure unencrypted private keys are never pushed to GitHub.